Retrieve raw SQL string from SqlDataAdapter query
I have been running a query in C# / SQL Server using SqlDataAdapter and adding parameters (Parameters.AddWithValue) in the form eg
da.SelectCommand.Parameters
.AddWithValue("@BSAgeParam2", Convert.ToInt32(BSAge_2.Texts)). 

I am looking to retrieve the actual raw string run (without the @ notation) in order to duplicate the query in SSMS and double check the results.
IS there a way to do this?

you can use SSMS SQL Server Profiler (under Tools)

You should still be able to use the parameterised query, you'll just need to make sure you set all the parameters.

You can get command text and parameters and create the raw query using string builder. Also, you can use the Profiler tool to see the executing command.

Getting used to SQL Server Profiler would be the way to go as @iSR5 recommended

The actual raw string that is passed is the parameterized one. The parameters are bound separately in the TDS protocol, and the server binds them as placeholders. No interpolation is done at any point, ever.


I am looking to retrieve the actual raw string run (without the @ notation) in order to duplicate the query in SSMS and double check the results. IS there a way to do this?

You already have it. The raw string has a parameter. Parameters are fundamental parts of most database providers, as it avoids SQL injection problems. If you want the equivalent code to use in SSMS: just add
declare @BSAgeParam2 int = 42;

(or whatever values) at the top of your SSMS window. Incidentally, this is exactly what MiniProfiler does for the SQL view.

Indeed, however the idea is not to declare it manually, because the parameters are chosen via comboboxes/datetimepickers etc, so it would be a pain to do it manually. However, I think SQL Server Profiler works!!
